# Guardar datos de formularios en MySQL

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo 3 tablas en mi base de datos en mysql, en el html cree tres formularios para cada tabla. quisiera que me apoyen en enviar los datos a cada tabla.

```
  <!-- Header -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #1565c0; padding-left: 25%;">
        <!-- Navbar content -->
        <img src="img/logo-untrm.svg" alt="">
      </nav>
 <div class="container">
        <!-- Content here -->

<!-- FORMULARIO -->
  <form id="regiration_form"  method="post">

<!-- FORMULARIO 1 -->
  <fieldset >
    <h2 class="text01">INGRESA TUS DATOS PERSONALES</h2>
    <div class="container-move">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fName">Apellido paterno</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Apaterno" id="fName" ">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fName">Apellido materno</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Amaterno" id="fName" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fName">Nombres</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fName" id="fName" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fName">Edad</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Aedado" id="fName" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fName">Fecha De Nacimiento</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Anacimiento" id="fName" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fName">Dni</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Aedado" id="fName" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fName">Número de celular</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Acontacto" id="fName" >
  </div>

   </div>

    <input type="button" name="password" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />
  </fieldset>

<!-- FORMULARIO 2 -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="text01"> EVALUCION SOCIOECONOMICA </h2>
    <div class="container-move">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fName">Apellidos Del Padre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Apadre" id="fName" >
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fName">Nombres Del Padre</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Npadre" id="fName">
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fName">Profesión Del Padre</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Ppadre" id="fName">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fName">Ingresos Promedio Del Padre</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="fName">
        <option>Menos de 300 soles</option>
        <option>Mas de 300 soles</option>
        <option>400 a 950 soles</option>
        <option>1000 a 2000 soles</option>
        <option>2000 a 5000 soles</option>
        <option>Mas de 5000 soles</option>
      </select>

 </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fName">Apellidos De La Madre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Amadre" id="fName" >
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fName">Nombres De La Madre</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Nmadre" id="fName">
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fName">Profesión Del La Madre</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Pmadre" id="fName">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fName">Ingresos Promedio De La Madre</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="fName">
        <option>Menos de 300 soles</option>
        <option>Mas de 300 soles</option>
        <option>400 a 950 soles</option>
        <option>1000 a 2000 soles</option>
        <option>2000 a 5000 soles</option>
        <option>Mas de 5000 soles</option>
      </select>
  </div>

</div>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="ANTERIOR" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="SIGUIENTE" />

  </fieldset>


<!-- FORMULARIO 3-->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="text01">ELIGE LUGAR DONDE RENDIR DEL EXAMEN</h2>
    <div class="container-move">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fName">Sedes</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
            <option>CHACHAPOYAS</option>
            <option>BAGUA</option>
            <option>UTCUBAMBA</option>
            <option>RODRIGUEZ DE MENDOZA</option>
          </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="ANTERIOR" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit btn btn-success" value="GUARDAR INSCRIPCIÓN" />
  </fieldset>


  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Podrias contarnos que intentaste hasta ahora? por favor mira [ask]

Comment: Pon el código de la parte servidora donde vayas a guardar la información